# How to use "equals" in express-validator?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm trying to assert that 2 passwords match:

```
app.post('/users/signup', [
    check('email', 'email is not valid')
      .isEmail()
      .trim(),
    check('password')
      .isLength({ min: 4 })
      .withMessage('password must be at least 4 characters')
      .equals('passwordConfirmation'),
  ], (req, res) => {
    ...
```

I'm using `equals` but it is checking if `password` actually equals the string `'passwordConfirmation'` not the value `req.body.passwordConfirmation`

Answer (score 2):

You can not use it the way you want.

I'm guessing, in your form, or your request body, you have two fields:

- `password`
- `confirmPassword`

Which you are able to access via:

- `req.body.password`
- `req.body.confirmPassword`

If this is correct, then you will not able to verify using the `check` API that the two are equal since you don't have access to the `req` object at the point and time.

What you can do is write a wrapper middleware around `check`:

```
const check = require('express-validator/check')

exports.verifyPasswordsMatch = (req, res, next) => {
    const {confirmPassword} = req.body

    return check('password')
      .isLength({ min: 4 })
      .withMessage('password must be at least 4 characters')
      .equals(confirmPassword)
}
```

Then use the wrapper like so:

```
app.post('/users/signup', [
    check('email', 'email is not valid')
      .isEmail()
      .trim(),
    verifyPasswordsMatch,
  ], (req, res) => {
    ...
```

Above is untested, but hopefully shows what you need to do.

Comment: This isn't the best approach (and needs further code to work properly). express-validator has custom validators support, which have access to the `req` object. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013025/2083599 for details.

Comment: the custom validator worked and I think is overall a better approach. Thanks guys!